# jQuery AJAX load() function works but post() does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, http-post

I don't understand why this is returning data for me:

```
$('#load').load('/api/myData', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

But this is not:

```
$.post('/api/myData', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

This is so basic, I don't see what I can be doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: `.load()` sends a `GET` request, `.post` sends a `POST` request.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense now. My API controller must not be allowing the POST method. Thanks.